# Retrieving Data from Firebase real time Database to ListView

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I've problem storing data into `ListView` from database on **Firebase**, I'm using the method below it runs when I click on button,
here is the method I use

```
private void retrieveMyDataMethod(){
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String name = dataSnapshot.child(uid).child("name").getValue(String.class);
            String address = dataSnapshot.child(uid).child("address").getValue(String.class);

            String[] data = new String[]{
                    name, address
            };

            List<String> data_list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data));

            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data_list);

            listViewRe.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where is the question ????

Comment: @OussemaAroua "I've problem storing data into ListView from database on Firebase" the first line lol.... Please share the error/log cat when you click the button to extract that information. Might also be beneficial to have the response you are trying to extract.

Comment: @Nero what kind of problems ? crash ? no data ? wrong output ? hh that's what I mean .

Comment: @OussemaAroua don't ask me lol, I've asked the OP the same thing :) He/she should've been providing us with that information from the beginning

Comment: Please add your database structure and tell us what is the expected result. Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @OussemaAroua No data when i click on the button to call this method "retrieveMyDataMethod()".

Comment: @AlexMamo This is my database structure [link](http://prntscr.com/m2zm1q), I wanted to show a list view in the activity each row show detail, eg first row Name: cmon, second row Address: dude, third row.  I wanted the list view to be like that [link](http://prntscr.com/m2zo28)[link] details based on logged in user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.orderByChild("name");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            list.add(name);
        }
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in your `ListView` will be:

```
cmon
here
```

Comment: Thank you so much it solved more than 80% of my problem, the other 20% that i want to retrieve the name based on the uid i already saved it on String using `FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();` and for the String `String uid = user.getUid();`

Comment: Good to hear that :) but this sounds as a new issue which basically should be considered another question that cannot be answered in a comment. As a personal guess, I think that you should use another database reference but in order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question using a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: You owe it, my apologies.